# PHPUnit mock a function and return static value specially for singleton method

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpunit, singleton

I am writting test cases for one of my class which is depends on another class. I want to mock that depended function and want to return a static data.

I am trying to write PHPUnit test for one my class called `CacheManager`. which is depends on another class called `RestApiHandler`.

Here is my `CacheManager` class

```
<?php

// -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Sayem\Users;

class CacheManager
{
    use Traits\Singleton;

    private $usersCacheKey = 'au_users_data';
    private $userCacheKey = 'au_user_data';
    private $settings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->settings = ['cache-lifespan' => 6];
    }

    public function usersCache(): array
    {
        $refreshData = false;
        $cachedData = get_transient($this->usersCacheKey);

        if (false === $cachedData) {
            // Cache doesn't exist or has expired, so generate new data and set cache
            $refreshData = true;
            // phpcs:ignore Inpsyde.CodeQuality.NoElse.ElseFound
        } else {
            $data = unserialize($cachedData);
            if (isset($data['error']) && $data['error']) {
                // Error cache, so generate new data and set cache
                $refreshData = true;
            }
        }

        if ($refreshData) {
            $allUsers = RestApiHandler::instance()->allUsersApiRequest();
            set_transient(
                $this->usersCacheKey,
                serialize($allUsers),
                $this->hoursInSecond((int)$this->settings['cache-lifespan'])
            );
            return $allUsers;
        }

        return unserialize($cachedData);
    }
}
```

This is my `RestApiHandler` class

```
<?php

// -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Sayem\Users;

class RestApiHandler
{
    use Traits\Singleton;

    public function allUsersApiRequest(): array
    {
        $url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
        $response = \wp_remote_get($url);

        if (is_wp_error($response)) {
            // Handle the error here
            $errorMessage = $response->get_error_message();
            return [
                'error' => true,
                'content' => esc_html__("Something went wrong: ", 'awesome-users') . $errorMessage,
            ];
        }

        // $responseCode = \wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
        // $response_headers = wp_remote_retrieve_headers($response);
        $responseBody = \wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

        return json_decode($responseBody);
    }
}
```

This is singleton

```
<?php

// -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Sayem\Users\Traits;

/**
 * singleton purpose trait
 *
 *
 * @author sayedulsayem
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
trait Singleton
{
    private static $instance;

    public static function instance(): object
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

And this is my test class

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Sayem\Users\Tests\Unit;

use Brain\Monkey;
use Sayem\Users\CacheManager;

class CacheManagerTest extends AbstractUnitTestcase
{
    public function testUsersCacheIfCacheDoesNotExist()
    {
        $freshData = [
            (object)['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Dave'],
            (object)['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Eve'],
        ];

        Monkey\Functions\when('RestApiHandler::instance()->allUsersApiRequest')->justReturn($freshData);

        Monkey\Functions\when('get_transient')->justReturn(false);
        Monkey\Functions\when('set_transient')->justReturn(true);
        
        $cacheManager = CacheManager::instance();

        $result = $cacheManager->usersCache();

        $this->assertEquals($freshData, $result);
    }

}
```

I am getting errors from line number 19 of `CacheManagerTest` class. this is the error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Sayem\Users\Tests\Unit\CacheManagerTest::testUsersCacheIfCacheDoesNotExist
Brain\Monkey\Name\Exception\InvalidName: ''RestApiHandler::instance()->allUsersApiRequest'' is not a valid function name.
```

is this possible to mock that function? or do i need to refactor my code?

Answer (score 0):

As its [developer said](https://github.com/Brain-WP/BrainMonkey/issues/54), "Brain Monkey is a tool to mock functions, not class methods".
So, you should rather use Mockery or other mocking tools.

There are also two other issues that make testing this piece of code harder:

- Using static methods (to make singleton): static methods are generally hard to mock, as mocks overload an object's (a.k.a instance) properties, but static methods belong to the class.
- Inversion of Control: `CacheManager` depends on `RestApiHandler`, but instead of asking it gently (e.g. through the constructor), it creates/gets an instance itself. This makes it hard (and sometimes impossible) to replace that object with its mock.

Here's a simplified and more testable version of your code:

```php
// CacheManager.php
<?php

namespace App;

class CacheManager
{
    use Traits\Singleton;

    private RestApiHandler $api;

    public function __construct(RestApiHandler $api)
    {
        $this->api = $api;
    }

    public function usersCache(): array
    {
        return $this->api->allUsersApiRequest();
    }
}


// RestApiHelper.php
<?php

namespace App;

class RestApiHandler
{
    use Traits\Singleton;

    public function allUsersApiRequest(): array
    {
        return [(object)['id' => 1, 'name' => 'this will be replaced by mock']];
    }
}


// Traits/Singleton.php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait Singleton
{
    private static $instance;

    public static function instance(...$args): object
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self(...$args);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}


// tests/CacheManagerTest.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests;

use App\CacheManager;
use App\RestApiHandler;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Mockery;

class CacheManagerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testUsersCacheIfCacheDoesNotExist()
    {
        $freshData = [
            (object)['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Dave'],
            (object)['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Eve'],
        ];

        $api = Mockery::mock(RestApiHandler::class);
        $api->shouldReceive('allUsersApiRequest')->once()->andReturn($freshData);

        $cacheManager = CacheManager::instance($api);

        $result = $cacheManager->usersCache();

        $this->assertEquals($freshData, $result);
    }
}
```

You can see how testing got easier by requiring dependencies in the constructor. However, this code doesn't enforce a single instance of RestApiHelper. In a real-world code, you can configure an IoC container to use singletons (instead of instantiating objects every time).